# -bash: ./configure: Permission denied

Tags: bash, permissions

When I run the command `./configure` in Ubuntu for installation of the `siesta-3.2` software, bash complains with this: `./configure: Permission denied.` How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 13):

**Try making `./configure` executable.**

In a terminal, `cd` into the directory where `./configure` is (`cd /path/to/configure/containing/folder`), then run `chmod +x configure`, then try run `./configure` as you were before.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 7):

There are many possibilities for this error:

- This happens because you are trying to install from other drives. Copy the content in the home directory then try installing using ./configure.  Also change the permission using `chmod +x configure`
- Or you are trying to run the command on a mounted partition that had the "noexec" flag on.

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the bash-box and saying "noexec"-flag!

Answer (score 2):

It worked when I ran the following command on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sh ./configure
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1186628)